# Cloning code from master branch to local repository

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, git-clone

So, I'm cloning code from master branch to my local directory. And when i open the code in (INTELLIJ Idea) on lower right side its shows master branch but instead of master branch i want my own branch(Branch i made from master branch) so that i can do changes on code and commit it and the commits only goes to my branch not master branch.

I cloned from master branch and then used git checkout to switch to my branch but then the code also switches to the one i have on my branch instead of master branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but then the code also switches to the one I have on my branch instead of `master` branch.

That is expected. Switching to an existing branch will update the working tree to reflect the latest branch commit content.

You could create a new branch from `master` instead: that new branch would start from the code from `master`.

Comment: Can I do that without creating a new branch

Comment: @ChetanPratapSingh No, or you would remain on `master`, and any new commit there would update master. If you want to work from master, it is better to create a new branch.